# Getting typeError while adding item to cart

Tags: reactjs, react-context

These lines of codes are from MealItem.js

```
import MealItemForm from "./MealItemForm";
import classes from "./MealItem.module.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import CartContext from "../../../store/cart-context";

const MealItem = props => {

    const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);
    
    const price = `INR ${props.price.toFixed(2)}`;
    
    const addToCartHandler = amount => {
        cartCtx.addItem({
            id: props.id,
            name: props.name,
            amount: amount,
            price: props.price
        });
    };
    return <li className={classes.meal}>
                <div>
                    <h3>{props.name}</h3>
                    <div className={classes.description}>{props.description}</div>
                    <div className={classes.price}>{price}</div>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    <MealItemForm onAddToCart={addToCartHandler} />
                </div>
            </li>
};

export default MealItem;
```

and these codes are from cart-context.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext({
    items: [],
    totalAmount: 0,
    addItem: (item) => {},
    removeItem: (id) => {}
});

export default CartContext;
```

As you can see I have a function inside the `const CartContext` named addItem but when I try to access this, this gives an error
[image]

Comment: You need to show all relevant code, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please show your Provider

Comment: you are missing an important piece here ( Context Provider ) . context API in react gives you 2 things one is the provider and another is a consumer . https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @DennisVash I had updated the question! Uploaded the full project there tell me if I can do anything more to that helps you to understand :)

Comment: @Shyam Thanks for your comment but after adding `context.Provider` it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you didn't render the Context Provider, refer to [`useContext` API docs examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

```
<CartContext.Provider value={yourContextValues}>
  <MealItem/>
</CartContext.Provider>
```

Update:
You have a typo in `addItem`

```
const cartContext = {
  ...
  // Should be addItem
  adddItem: addItemToCartHandler,
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still It's not working :(  gives the same error

Comment: ahhhh .. got that typo :) thankyou so much for your assistance